# grunt-usemin + grunt-rev, point to CDN url on build but maintain revision number?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I'm using [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) in combination with [grunt-rev](https://github.com/cbas/grunt-rev) to replace references to non-optimized scripts with a single concatenated one, with a revision tacked on each build.

It takes this:

```
    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/main.js -->
    <script src="scripts/custom_script1.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/custom_script2.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/models/custom_model.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

and, after `grunt build`, outputs this:

```
<script src="scripts/b7197f7b.main.js"></script>
```

**Now here's my problem:**

I need the build output `src` to not be relative to the project directory, but rather point to an external URL, as my script will be hosted on a CDN.

```
// build should produce THIS instead:
<script src="www.my-cdn-url.com/scripts/b7197f7b.main.js"></script>
```

I've tried to do this using the [blockReplacement](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin#blockreplacements) config object in the usemin task:

```
// this is what I've tried (note the blockReplacement):
usemin: {
    html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
    css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
    options: {
        dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>'],
        blockReplacements: {
            js: function (block) {
                return '<script type="text/javascript" src="www.my-cdn-url.com/scripts/'+block.dest+'"></script>';
            }
        }
    }
},
```

And, while this works for changing the `src` attribute to point to my CDN, **the revision number is not being applied**.

**My Question: How can I point my usemin build to an external endpoint, while maintaining the revisioning number created during the build?**

For reference, here are my complete usemin and rev tasks (taken from the yeoman backbone boilerplate):

```
usemin: {
    html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
    css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
    options: {
        dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>'],
        blockReplacements: {
            js: function (block) {
                return '<script type="text/javascript" src="www.my-cdn-url.com/scripts/'+block.dest+'"></script>';
            },
            css: function(block) {
                return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="www.my-cdn-url.com/styles/'+block.dest+'">';
            }
        }
    }
},

rev: {
    dist: {
        files: {
            src: [
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp}',
                '/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found no way to do this with only `grunt-rev` and `grunt-usemin`, I needed to bring in an additional grunt plugin: `grunt-cdnify`.

Below is how the Cdnify task configuration to get my desired result:

```
cdnify: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            base: '//my-cdn-url.com',
            cc: true
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'dist',
            src: 'index.html',
            dest: 'dist'
        }]
    }
}
```

the `/scripts/` and `/styles/` are being appended to the base URL naturally. Was unfortunate I needed an additional plugin to do something so simple, but hey it works!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can access the revved filename through `grunt.filerev.summary`. Here you can find an example: [blockReplacements run before filerev linking](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/444#issuecomment-193955669)